# Can we display multiple objects in swagger put API request body

Tags: java, rest, swagger

Swagger request body showing single object at a time even though it accepts list of objects, i have a doubt that can we display list of objects in put API swagger doc by default

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Yes, according to docs you can add array example.
(https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/)

**Less short answer:**

It depends all on *schema* and *definitions* sections in swagger definition. There is an example yaml file for swagger editor (https://editor.swagger.io/) which contains array definition with simple values, objects and examples for them.

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
    info:a
      version: 1.0.0
      title: Privacy-Service API
    paths:
      /allNames:
        put:
          consumes:
            - application/json
          produces:
            - application/json
          parameters:
            - name: request
              in: body
              schema:
                $ref: '#/definitions/ArrayOfNames'
          responses:
            '200':
              description: List of names
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: string
                  
      /allAddresses:
        put:
          consumes:
            - application/json
          produces:
            - application/json
          parameters:
            - name: request
              in: body
              schema:
                $ref: '#/definitions/ArrayOfAddresses'
          responses:
            '200':
              description: List of addresses
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object  
                  
    definitions:
      ArrayOfNames:
        type: array
        items:
          minItems: 1
          type: object
          required:
            - name
          properties:
            name:
              type: string
        example: ["name":"John", "name" : "Arthur", "name": "Thomas"]
      
        
      ArrayOfAddresses:
        type: array
        items:
          minItems: 1
          type: object
          required:
            - city
            - street
            - houseNumber
          properties:
            city:
              type: string
            street:
              type: string
            houseNumber:
              type: number
        example:
          - city: Knoxville
            street: Raver Croft Drive
            houseNumber: 225
          - city: Gates Mills
            street: Simpson Avenue
            houseNumber: 4636
```